# What is the lightest and lease resource intensive PHP forum software

Tags: php, mysql

Only the most basic of features are needed. Nothing fancy, no graphics, rating system, avatars, etc. All text

Comment: Why don't you simply build one yourself? This is a very simple task when it is just a simple text based discussion

Answer (score 1):

[Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/) perhaps